# How to move mouse pointer using a compact keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.10, mouse, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10/18.04 and I'm wondering if there is a way to move the mouse pointer using the keyboard only with a compact keyboard. I know that in Settings under Universal Access, I can enable the 'Mouse Keys' option, but it's not working with my keyboard because not has the keypad. Sidenote: the keyboard also not has a virtual keypad(Fn key + some keys).

Could I set some shortcuts to do this?

Is available software to do this? Alternatives?

Thanks in advance for answers.